# How to make textbox appear only after user clicks button in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I make a textbox appear only after clicking a button. THis means that It should be hidden, and once user clicks, then it can appear.

```
 private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        // .. what next?      
 }
```

Comment: Are you telling the control to `.Hide()` when you initially load your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Control.Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make any control visible or hidden:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    theTextBox.Visible = true;
}
```

Just set it's `Visible` property to `false` initially (ie: in the designer).

Comment: I tried your method but the textbox is already appearing from before when I run my application

Comment: @user7068 Read the last sentence there - you need to set the `Visible` property to `false` in the designer, so it's hidden by default.

Comment: `TextBox` doesn't have a property called `Visible` in WPF. Instead it has a property called `Visibility` and a readonly property called `IsVisible`. The tags or the answer should be updated.

Comment: @FredrikHedblad This is Windows Forms, not WPF (look at the event declaration syntax - if it was WPF, it'd be `RoutedEventArgs`, not `EventArgs`) - I'll fix the tag ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have defined a `TextBox textBox1` somewhere:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Visible = !textBox1.Visible;      
}
```

This way you can toggle the visibility.

You can set it just to `true` if you like, but make sure the initial `Visible` state, you can set it in the designer, is `false`.